# Validating StringLength but reserving more space on DB column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a password field that i would like the user type only between 5 to 10 characters.

However, i will apply md5 and save that value, so i need more space than 10. But StringLength sets nvarchar to 10.

```
[Required, StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 5)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Resuming, I want to use that validation but thats not what I want to use in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should ideally make 2 models. One view model for binding to the posted values and other as a DB model.